# Cannot set a specific language to DatePicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I'm trying to set as `DatePicker` locale the `CurrentCulture`, what I did so far:

**XAML Definition**

```
xmlns:glob="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
```

**DatePicker structure**

```
<DatePicker Language="{Binding Source={x:Static glob:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"  />
```

the problem's I got this exception:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' and 'System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='CultureInfo' (HashCode=-1158415740); target element is 'DatePicker' (Name='MatchCalendarDate'); target property is 'Language' (type 'XmlLanguage')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='it-IT' BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='CultureInfo' (HashCode=-1158415740); target element is 'DatePicker' (Name='MatchCalendarDate'); target property is 'Language' (type 'XmlLanguage')

Note that I'm using as `DatePicker` control the MahApp.

Comment: you can do like this <DatePicker xml:lang="en-US"/>

Comment: @Rise I've a multilanguage application, so each time that the app start, this need to initialize the DatePicker to the currentLocale in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set the `Language` property to a `CultureInfo` object and this won't work. You need to set it to a `XmlLanguage`.

Unfortunately you cannot set it to the language of the current culture in pure XAML, but you could easily do the exact same thing programmatically:

```
dp.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```

---

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dp" />
```

And this certainly does not break the MVVM pattern in any way since you set the exact same property in the exact same view.

Comment: is possible bound Language to a property? I tried with: `public string GetCurrentCulture
        {
            get { return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag; }
        }` but the application goes to interruption mode

Comment: Setting the language does absolutely nothing???  I am on an English system, have set the dt.Language to "en-GB" and still the data shows American style.

Comment: This setting changes the language of the words as well as the date format. It is not usual for applications to also change the formats when the user changes the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attached property to change language like this

```
  public class AttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SetLanguageProperty =
                DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SetLanguage", typeof(bool), typeof(AttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSetLanguageChanged));

        private static void OnSetLanguageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as DatePicker).Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        }
        public static bool GetSetLanguage(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(SetLanguageProperty);
        }
        public static void SetSetLanguage(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SetLanguageProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

in xaml

```
<DatePicker local:AttachedProperties.SetLanguage="True"/>
```